# How does Magento2 generate the JavaScript Bundling?

Tags: magento2, javascript

With the JavaScript Bundling configuration active, Magento2 combine the JS into a series of bundles:

[image: Magento2 JavaScript Bundles]

This scripts don't seem generated by RequireJS, so how does Magento know which modules to include for each page and in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Javascript Settings -> Enable Javascript Bundling` set to `Yes`

After above configuration.

`magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Asset\Config.php` that flag is called here

```
/**
 * Check whether bundling of JavScript files is on
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isBundlingJsFiles()
{
    return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        self::XML_PATH_JS_BUNDLING,
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

`magento\vendor\magento\module-require-js\Block\Html\Head\Config.php`

```
/**
 * Include RequireJs configuration as an asset on the page
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{

    if ($this->bundleConfig->isBundlingJsFiles()) { // Check for that FLAG
    }
}
```

So whenever module or theme's JS called from `requirejs-config.js`. It will check this flag & if flag is set it will bundle (merge) JS for that Module/Theme respectively.

Can refer below files more detail

`magento\vendor\magento\module-require-js\Model\FileManager.php`

```
public function createBundleJsPool()
{
}
```

`magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager.php`